# Migrating FileStream database to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, filestream

We are migrating our existing client databases to Azure soon.  Our current database uses FileStream and has some data stored in columns of type `varbinary(max)`. From what I have read, FileStream is not supported in Azure.

How would we be able to migrate this data to Azure?  Hopefully this isn't repeat, but I have not been able to find an example of someone doing this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported in Azure SQL Databases, but you have two other options. One is to simply use a VM with a SQL Server installed and the other one, and recommended, is to use the newly announced SQL Server Managed Instances.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/migrate-your-databases-to-a-fully-managed-service-with-azure-sql-database-managed-instance/

Comment: But can we use Azure Storage for SQL Server FileStream? If so, how?

Comment: Based on [Filestream and Filetable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-transact-sql-information#filestream-and-filetable) limitations in Azure SQL Database Managed Instance, it would appear not.